# Ulimit no file just won't change (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, ulimit

I followed everything I could find on how to change the maximum value of ulimit nofile but it's still stuck at 4096. Both my `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and `/etc/systemd/user.conf` have the line `DefaultLimitNOFILE=1048576` and in `/etc/security/limits.conf` there are the lines

```
<myusername> hard nofile 1048576
<myusername> soft nofile 1048576
```

But the return of `ulimit -Hn` is 4096 and `ulimit -n 1048576` doesn't work. Is there something else I need to do ? Thanks.